# How to open a new tab in Background in Chrome using AppleScript

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

How to open a new tab in Background using AppleScript in chrome.
Open a tab seems so easy, but I just can't find what can be called to open the tab in background, which means the active tab remains the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can save the `active tab index` in a variable and set it back after you created your tab:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set activeIndex to get active tab index of window 1
    tell window 1
        set newTab to make new tab with properties {URL:"http://www.google.com/"}
    end tell
    set active tab index of window 1 to activeIndex
end tell
```

Comment: any idea how do I close the newly opened tab after say 2 sec delay ?